# IPC - Excel and .Net app

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to define a small function, ZipDistance, in VBA, which calculates a distance between two zip codes. Since I have such a function in a .Net application, it would be easiest for me just to execute this app with the correct parameters and then reading the result back in.

The parameters to the .net app, is two zipcodes (i.e. integers), and the result of the computation is an integer.

something like the following would work just fine.

```
Dim ret as Integer
ret = Execute("my-net-app.exe 9000 8000")
```

Any suggestions on how to do that? Anything from exit code, using standard out from the .net app to reading to a file and parsing that file in excel will be acceptable. As long as it is fairly simple.

Comment: Solved. Sort of! I realized that the problem domain could be simplified quite heavily. Instead of being the factorial of ~1600 zipcodes, we will only need about ~1500 zipcodes totally. As such I simply bulkloaded them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are asking for is *Shell()* in my understanding. But this does not return the return of your exe, but the "task-ID" of the application, according to online help. To communicate with your application you need automation, IMO.

Well, if your exe's output can be redirected on the console to a text file (

```
Shell "my-net-app.exe 9000 8000 > g:\distance\result.txt"
```

), you can use good old Open:

```
Dim intFile As Integer, strDistance As String
intFile = Freefile
Open "g:\distance\result.txt" For Input As #intFile
Input #intFile, strDistance
Close #intFile
```

I have not even checked the syntax details, this is just to show the path. I have done reading complex files (rebuilt TransferText this way), so I know it works.

I would not recommend it though. This is not the way single information pieces should be passed from program to program. Since I would not like the hassle of automating a small program like this I would rebuild the function in VBA.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, an overly complex method of simply getting the exit code out. I have already tried a similar approach, and can tell that it is even more complex. You have to load special libraries and use hooks to wait for termination of the external command and stuff. But, as far as I have found, the only alternative to this, is setting up a web service, which is likely to be even more complex.